# Postgresql count rows per date adding up

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, cumulative-sum

I'm trying to make a diagram where I can follow the increasing user numbers.

Therefore I wrote a SQL statement searching for newly added users in a specific period:

```
select distinct Createtime, count (user_id) as new_users 
from user 
where createtime between '2015-12-03 00:00:00' and CURRENT_DATE 
group by createtime 
order by createtime asc;
```

The following result is shown:

```
createtime|new_users
---------------------
2015-12-04|    1
2016-01-20|    1     
2016-02-03|    5
2016-02-04|    1
```

I would like to add up the results to have the current number of users for each of the dates, so the result should look more like this:

```
createtime|new_users
---------------------
2015-12-04|    1
2016-01-20|    2     
2016-02-03|    7
2016-02-04|    8
```

Is there a SQL statement or a different way to achieve this? I hope you can help me with this.

Comment: Do you store dates or timestamps in the createtime column?

Comment: I use timestamp without timezone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with a window function:

```
select createtime, sum(new_users) over (order by createtime) as new_users
from (
  select createtime::date as createtime, count(user_id) as new_users 
  from "user"
  where createtime between '2015-12-03 00:00:00' and CURRENT_DATE 
  group by createtime 
) t
order by createtime asc;
```

---

`user` is a reserved keyword and needs to be quoted, otherwise you can't use it as an identifier.

Comment: How do I eliminate the duplicated timestamps? There are dates from the same day however different during different times a day

Comment: Never mind, I solved it with a cast in the from satement (cast createtime as date) and distinct

Comment: @user3906778: I assumed those were dates, because you didn't do that in your original query either.

Comment: Yes you`re right. I edited the post. Thank you for your help! It works great!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select x.Createtime, 
(select count (sub.user_id) from USER sub 
WHERE sub.createtime between '2015-12-03 00:00:00' and x.Createtime )as new_users 
from user x
where createtime between '2015-12-03 00:00:00' and CURRENT_DATE 
group by createtime 
order by createtime asc;
```